# cannot play the wav file...In Android.!

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder

I am trying to append two wav files in Android.For that i read both files to 2 byte array(A&B).And i combined both of them to a new array (C).And i writed the contents in the third array C to a new .wav output file.Also i put the wav header file.I get the out put file of size(C=A+B).But The player failed to play that output file.

If the second input file(B) does not read to byte array(here i initialize  B .But Not writing the contents of the second file to byte array ,B),then i can play the output file,here first file fully plays but after the player is silent(in place of 2nd file)..

I used the following Snippets for that: please help to solve this issue

```
File firstFile=new File("path1.wav");
        File secondFile=new File("path2.wav");

        int size1=(int)firstFile.length();
        int size2=(int)secondFile.length();

        Log.i("Size1::"+size1,"Size2::"+size2);

        dataOne=new byte[size1];
        dataTwo=new byte[size2];




        newData=new byte[dataOne.length+dataTwo.length];


        try 
        {
            in1=new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(firstFile)));
            in2=new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(secondFile)));


            in1.readFully(dataOne);
            in1.close();
            in2.read(dataTwo);
            in2.close();

            int j;
            for(j=0;j<dataOne.length;j++)
                newData[j]=dataOne[j];
            for(int m=0;m<dataTwo.length;m++)
                newData[j+m]=dataTwo[j];




        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try 
        {
            fWriter = new FileOutputStream("outputPath.wav");


            WAVE(fWriter);

            //fWriter.write(newData,0,newData.length);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and  i use the following two methods for wav header creation

```
public void WAVE(FileOutputStream fWriter)
{

    try 
    {
        //0------------3
        fWriter.write('R');
        fWriter.write('I');
        fWriter.write('F');
        fWriter.write('F');


        //4------7

        byte[] res=new byte[4];

        int sizeOfFile=newData.length-8;
        res=toBytes(sizeOfFile);
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            Log.i(""+j,""+res[j]);
        fWriter.write(res,0,4);




        //8-15
        fWriter.write('W');
        fWriter.write('A');
        fWriter.write('V');
        fWriter.write('E');
        fWriter.write('f');
        fWriter.write('m');
        fWriter.write('t');
        fWriter.write(' ');

        //16----19
         res=new byte[4];
        res=toBytes(16);
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            Log.i(""+j,""+res[j]);
        fWriter.write(res,0,4);


        //20---21
        res=toBytes(1);
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            Log.i("PCM"+j,""+res[j]);
        fWriter.write(res,0,2);

        //22---23
        res=toBytes(2);
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            Log.i("NOC:MONO/STEREO"+j,""+res[j]);
        fWriter.write(res,0,2);

        //24--27
        int ASR=Integer.parseInt(44100);  
        res=toBytes(ASR);
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            Log.i(ASR+"ASR"+j,""+res[j]);
        fWriter.write(res,0,4);

        //28--31 Bytes Per Second

        int Number_of_channels=2;
        int Samples_per_second=ASR;
        int Bits_per_Sample=32;
        int BPS=Number_of_channels*Samples_per_second*Bits_per_Sample/8;
                Integer.parseInt(audioSamplingRate);
        res=toBytes(BPS);
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            Log.i(ASR+"BPS"+j,""+res[j]);
        fWriter.write(res,0,4);


        //32--33 Block Alignment

        int BA= Number_of_channels*Bits_per_Sample/8;

        res=toBytes(BA);
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            Log.i("Block Alignment"+j,""+res[j]);
        fWriter.write(res,0,2);

        //34---35  Bits Per Sample

        res=toBytes(Bits_per_Sample);
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            Log.i(ASR+"Bits Per Sample"+j,""+res[j]);
        fWriter.write(res,0,2);


        //36---39 "data"
        fWriter.write('d');
        fWriter.write('a');
        fWriter.write('t');
        fWriter.write('a');

        //40----43 length of data
        res=toBytes(newData.length);
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            Log.i("Data Size"+j,""+res[j]);
        fWriter.write(res,0,4);

        fWriter.write(newData);

        fWriter.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
 public byte[] toBytes(int i)
{
  byte[] result = new byte[4];

  result[0] = (byte) (i >> 24);
  result[1] = (byte) (i >> 16);
  result[2] = (byte) (i >> 8);
  result[3] = (byte) (i /*>> 0*/);

  return result;
}
```

And i use API 8 (2.2 Froyo)

Comment: just go through this link ..hope it is helpful for you..  
http://computermusicblog.com/blog/2008/08/29/reading-and-writing-wav-files-in-java

Comment: i already refferd that link but no use for me !!!!!!

Comment: so you want to play that output file outside the program or is it ok if you play that file from your code ...

Comment: I wish to play file inside my program

Comment: please show your logcat output when you try to play the file with 2 wav files together.

Comment: @Emil Adj.I didn't tryed to play the out put file inside my progra..I plyed the file from sdcard.In sd card i can play both the first and second file but the the output can't.Did you think it will ply on my pgm?

Comment: Have you checked out Soundpool class in android ..It is useful to play wav files ..Heres the sample link..Have a look at it..cheers..

http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/06/27/android-soundpool-how-to-check-if-sound-file-is-loaded/